# maven: replace imports to create separate artifacts for javax and jakarta

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I've built a small servlet utility lib that is currently using `javax.servlet` namespace (let's call it `my-servlet-utils-1.0.0.jar`) and now I want to automate the process of creating `jakarta.servlet` version (`my-servlet-utils-1.0.0-jakarta.jar`) using maven. I know how to replace `javax.servlet` dependencies with `jakarta.servlet` and add `-jakarta` classifier using maven build profiles, but I don't know how to automate replacing `import`s in my java files. Currently I run a `sed` script before building `-jakarta` version, but I'm looking for a better way (integrated into maven) to do this. Thanks!

**update:** running my `sed` script from maven using `maven-antrun-plugin` does not really improve things as it modifies the java files directly in the source tree, which confuses `git` related tools and creates a danger of committing such modified files. I'm looking for a solution that will modify the sources somewhere in `target` folder.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look maven-shade-plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise could you please explain what do you have in mind? I don't see how shading is related here, but maybe I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a decent looking overview listing several possible approaches: maven-shade-plugin, eclipse transformer tool, tomcat transformer tool, and so on https://tomee.apache.org/javax-to-jakarta.html